# AS3 Character jumping/falling problems

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, game-physics

I am having problems with getting the character to jump/fail when the up arrow is pressed. I'm trying to make it so when the up arrow key is pressed once it will jump a certain height then fall.

Here is my movement  code:

```
public var gravity:int = 2;



public function fireboyMovement(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) //right
        {
            fireboy1.x = fireboy1.x -5;
            checkBorder()

        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 39) //left
        {
            fireboy1.x = fireboy1.x +5;
            checkBorder()

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) //up
        {
            fireboy1.y = fireboy1.y -20;
            fireboy1.y += gravity;
            checkBorder()
        }
```

Comment: Please be more clear.  "Problem" doesn't mean anything to someone reading your question.    My guess is that you'd like it to keep moving until the up key is released?   In which case, you'd just need to run an enter frame handler or timer in between the key down and key up events (I'll show an example if that is indeed what you're looking to do)

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question now. I want it so when the up arrow key is pressed once it will jump a certain height then fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you need to increment the players position over time (and not all at once).

You can either use a tweening engine (like tweenlite), or roll your own timer or enter frame handler.

Here is an example of the latter:

```
    if (e.keyCode == 38) //up
    {
        if(!isJumping){
            isJumping = true;
            velocity = 50;  //how much to move every increment, reset every jump to default value
            direction = -1; //start by going upwards
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,jumpLoop);
        }
    }
```

---

```
var isJumping:Boolean = false;
var friction:Number = .85; //how fast to slow down / speed up - the lower the number the quicker (must be less than 1, and more than 0 to work properly)
var velocity:Number;
var direction:int = -1;

function jumpLoop(){ //this is running every frame while jumping 
    fireboy1.y += velocity * direction; //take the current velocity, and apply it in the current direction
    if(direction < 0){
        velocity *= friction; //reduce velocity as player ascends
    }else{
        velocity *= 1 + (1 - friction); //increase velocity now that player is falling
    }

    if(velocity < 1) direction = 1; //if player is moving less than 1 pixel now, change direction
    if(fireboy1.y > stage.stageHeight - fireboy1.height){  //stage.stageheight being wherever your floor is
        fireboy1.y = stage.stageHeight - fireboy1.height; //put player on the floor exactly
        //jump is over, stop the jumpLoop
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,jumpLoop);
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```